# Is there a way to run Java in R?

Tags: java, r, machine-learning

I am working on a project which is primarily in R and requires Java to run. So, I need a way to run Java in R itself.

For example, is there any way to run this code in R?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

     System.out.println("HelloWorld");

 }

}
```

** Lib in R (v8,rJava,rserve)

Comment: As a  pure programming question, this is off-topic on Cross Validated - see  our [help/on-topic] - but should be on-topic on Stack Overflow. We can migrate if for you if there is consensus for it here.

Comment: That code snippet is absolutely *not* javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first google result for ["javascript in r"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20in%20R) that I got leads to [vignette of `js` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/js/vignettes/intro.html), that uses [`V8` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/v8_intro.html) providing [V8 implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) of JavaScript for R. You can use either of the packages to run JS code from R.

Comment: This is helpful information, but the code posted in the question is Java, not JavaScript.